# how to create procedure about Fragmentation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need create maintenance procedure (Full database) about Fragmentation if Fragmentation > 30% run rebuild else run Reorganize.

I try to look up this procedure but I could not find anything about that..

If you have any link about it or can create this procedure please help me.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, use [Ola's Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For example you can get the list of indexes with

```
SELECT S.name as [Schema],
  T.name as [Table],
  I.name as [Index],
  cast (DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as decimal(5,2))  avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
DDIPS.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
   and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc;
```

Based on https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-identify-and-resolve-sql-server-index-fragmentation/